# Building an angular 12 application not working in gitlab runner

Tags: node.js, angular, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to build an angular 12 application with a gitlab runner (executor shell, node 12, npm 6).

I have the following error with `ng build`:

```
Compiling @angular/material/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
runtime: nameOff 0x6b61565a out of range 0xd840 - 0x201ac5
fatal error: runtime: name offset out of range
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x83a95, 0x21})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1198 +0x7 fp=0x476880 sp=0x476858 pc=0x12000007
runtime.resolveNameOff(0xe28a, 0x6b61565a)
```

If I execute the `ng build` directly from the VM where the runner is installed, everything works fine (with the same user `gitlab-runner`).

However when it is executed in the pipeline, it fails.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. 
Have you identified a solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution but a workaround: in a shell executor, I use a docker node-12 image to execute 'npm install'.